Step in proof of $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$
I would appreciate any help understanding the following step in evaluating the above integral. I'm struggling as my lecturer skips many fundamental steps, and I have some trouble filling the missing parts.

We define $f(z)=\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2}$, and we wish to find $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz$, where $\gamma$ is the curve in the above figure. My issue is with evaluating the integral over $\gamma_{\varepsilon}$ (the half circle with radius $\varepsilon$). We can parametrize this curve with $\gamma_{\varepsilon} = -\varepsilon e^{-it}$ for $t \in [0,\pi]$. My only idea so far was to use the Taylor expansion of $e^z$ to obtain:
$$ 
\int_{\gamma_{\varepsilon}}f(z)dz=\int_{\gamma_{\varepsilon}}\frac{1-(1+iz+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(iz)^n}{n!})}{z^2}dz=  
\int_{\gamma_{\varepsilon}}\frac{-iz-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(iz)^n}{n!}}{z^2}dz
$$
After splitting the integral into two integrals, the left integral can be simplified when plugging in $z=\gamma_{\varepsilon}(t)$ and $dz=\gamma_{\varepsilon}'(t)dt$. But I'm not sure what to do with the right integral (containing the infinite sum). Specifically, I'm having trouble with rigoursly justifying the multiple changes in the order of limits. I also believe I don't have to explicitly use the sum but to use the first order remainder of the Taylor expansion of $e^z$, but again I'm not sure how to formalize the justficiation for interchanging the order of limits.
Edit: after reading the answer here, I still struggle to understand why $E(z)$ is bounded. Additionaly, I do understand that since:
$$ 
\int_{\gamma_{\varepsilon}^{+}} \frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2} dz = \int_{\gamma_{\varepsilon}^{+}} \frac{-i}{z} dz + \int_{\gamma_{\varepsilon}^{+}} E(z) dz
$$
the left integral is $-\pi$, but why does the right integral tend to $0$ when $\varepsilon \to 0$?

Do not use the Taylor expansion. You completely lose control as $r\to\infty$. Try to explore other options.

@Sebastiano Edited and added clarification.

@RatherAmusing Rectract my closure .

To see why $E(z)$ is bounded, note that $E(z) = \frac{1+iz-e^{iz}}{z^2}$. Use the Taylor expansion of $e^{iz} $ and remember that convergent $\implies$ bounded. Also I guess the ML inequality was used to conclude that its integral tends to zero.

@DavideMasi But why does $E(z)$ converge to $0$ when $z \to 0$? Am I missing some fundamental notions regarding Taylor expansions? If I remember correctly, $E(z)$ would converge to $0$ when $z \to 0$ if the denumerator were $z$, not $z^2$

It's not $E(z) $ that converges to $0$ but its integral. Write $E(z)$ like I said. If you expand $e^{iz}$, the first two terms will cancel out $1+iz$ and the other terms of the expansion all share a factor $z^2$ which cancel the $z^2$ in the denominator

@DavideMasi Thank you!

The key is ML-inequality theorem.
$$I=\int_{\gamma_{\varepsilon}}f(z)dz=I_1+I_2$$
where
$$I_1=-\int_{\gamma_{\varepsilon}}\frac izdz=-\int_\pi^0\frac i{\varepsilon e^{i\theta}}i\varepsilon e^{i\theta}d\theta=-\pi$$ and
$$I_2=\int_{\gamma_{\varepsilon}}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(iz)^{n-2}}{n!}
$$
By MLIT,
$$|I_2|\leq ML=\left(\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\varepsilon^{n-2}}{n!}\right)(\pi\varepsilon)=\pi\frac{e^\varepsilon-\varepsilon-1}{\varepsilon}\rightarrow0$$
as $\varepsilon\to0.$ So is $I_2\to0$.

Observe that $f(z)=\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2}$ has a simple pole at $0$ (you can check this fact using its Laurent series).
The following result holds: you can find it as Corollary $5.4.8$ in "Complex Analysis with Applications" by Asmar and Grafakos; in case you need them I will add more details.

Suppose that $g$ is an analytic function in a deleted neighborhood of $z_0$ with a simple pole at $z_0$. For $ 0<r \le r_0$, let $\sigma_r$ be the circular arc at angle $\alpha$. 
Then we have $$\lim_{r\to 0^+} \int_{\sigma_r} g(z) dz = i \alpha \text{ Res}(g,z_0)$$

Here, $\alpha = \pi$. What is left is to evaluate $\text{Res}(f,0) $.
